# Error: 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous' when working with DataCamp Nobel Project

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not sure how to resolve this error, as I can run all the code without any apparent issues. When I run the code, I receive the following error message:
'Your solution doesn't look quite right
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

```
# Loading in required libraries
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# Start coding here!

df = pd.read_csv('data/nobel.csv')

# most commonly awarded gender and birth country 
top_gender = df.sex.value_counts().index[0]
top_country = df.birth_country.value_counts().index[0]

# Calculate the proportion of USA born winners per decade
df['usa_born_winner'] = df['birth_country'] == 'United States of America'
df['decade'] = np.floor(df.year / 10) * 10
df['decade'] = df['decade'].astype(int)

# Identify the decade with the highest proportion of US-born winners
max_decade_usa = df.groupby('decade', as_index=False)['usa_born_winner'].mean()
max_decade_usa = max_decade_usa.loc[max_decade_usa['usa_born_winner'].idxmax(), 'decade']


# Calculating the proportion of female laureates per decade
max_female_dict = df.groupby(['decade', 'category'], as_index=False)['female_winner'].mean()

# Find the decade and category with the highest proportion of female laureates
max_female_dict = max_female_dict.loc[max_female_dict['female_winner'].idxmax(), ['decade', 'category']]
max_female_dict = {max_female_dict['decade']: max_female_dict['category']}


# Finding the first woman to win a Nobel Prize
woman = df[df['female_winner'] == True]
min_row = woman[woman['year'] == woman['year'].min()]
first_woman_name = min_row['full_name']
first_woman_category = min_row['category']

# Selecting the laureates that have received 2 or more prizes
repeats = df.full_name.value_counts()
repeats = repeats[repeats >= 2].index
repeat_list = list(repeats)
```

Can someone help me understand the cause of this error and provide guidance on how to fix it?
I appreciate any help or insights into resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Let me know if you have understood my answer or need further help.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience this always happens when there is something wrong with bolean indexing, as for your case I think its in the

```
min_row = woman[woman['year'] == woman['year'].min()]
```

line because the result can contain more than one row to fix add .iloc[0] that is

```
min_row = woman[woman['year'] == woman['year'].min()].iloc[0]
```

**because I dont have your nobel.csv file I cannot check it myself and ensure this will work so please let me know if it works for you**